# How to use replaceFirst() to get a series of sequential strings in my case?

Tags: java, string, replace

My input string uid contains 6 characters, and there are 0~6 '?' at random position like "00??00", "0?00?0", "0??00?". For example, if the input is "00?0?0", I want to replace two '?' with 0~9. So the results should be `"000000","000010","000020"..."000090","001000","001010"..."001090"..."009090"`

Well, my following code can only get `"000000","001010","002020"..."009090"`, I got to know that replace() will replace all '?', and using replaceFirst() might solve it. So how to use replaceFirst() to get the results I want?

```
List<Get> gets = new ArrayList<>();  

for (int i =0; i<10; i++){
    get = new Get((uid.replace(uid.charAt(2), (char) (i + '0'))).getBytes());  

    // get = new Get((uid.replaceFirst("\\?", "0+i")).getBytes());     

    gets.add(get);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lengthy solution. But it works,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String patt = "0?0?00";
        List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
        a.add(patt);
        while (true) {
            List<String> b = generateAndGet(a);
            if (b.size() == 0) {
                break;
            }
            a = b;
        }
        for (String item : a) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
        return;
    }



    private static List<String> generateAndGet(List<String> val) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String item : val) {
            final char[] itemArray = item.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
                if (itemArray[i] == '?') {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) { 
                        itemArray[i] = (char) (j + '0');
                        result.add(String.copyValueOf(itemArray)); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [String#format()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-), the advantage with that approach instead of **replace()** is that you can keep the 2 places by adding leading zeros to the string you generate...

see this example and optimize it removing the unnecessary creation of string objects...

```
String patt = "00??00";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    String numberWithLeadingZeros = String.format("%02d", i);
    String x = String.format(patt.replace("??", "%s"), numberWithLeadingZeros);
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

our final result will be something as:

"000000","000100","000200"..."000900","001000","001100"..."001900"..."009900"

Comment: So, what if two '?' are not adjacent， like "00?0?0", and I want to get "000000","000010","000020"..."000090"..."001000"..."001090"..."009090"   how to solve it? Thanks~

Comment: then you have to expose that before you ask the question, there is  no universal solution for the example input you posted

Answer (score 1):

```
String patter = "00??00";
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    System.out.println(patt.replace("??", ""+i));
}
```

Comment: the output will be 00100,00200,...009900. Number of digits will be one less till i equal to 10